# How do I run my Rock Paper Scissors Game?

Tags: javascript

I just got into JavaScript and I wrote a simple rock paper scissors game, but I am unable to actually make it run.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
var computerChoice = math.random()
if (computerChoice < 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "Rock"
} else if (computerChoice < 0.66) {
  computerChoice = "Paper"
} else {
  computerChoice = "Scissors"
};
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "Tie, no one wins!"
  }
};
if (userChoice === "Rock") {
  if (computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    return "You win!"
  } else if (computerChoice === "Paper") {
    return "You lose!"
  }
};
if (userChoice === "Paper") {
  if (computerChoice === "Rock") {
    return "You win!"
  } else if (computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    return "You Lose!"
  }
};
if (userChoice === "Scissors") {
  if (computerChoice === "Paper") {
    return "You win!"
  } else if (computerChoice === "Rock") {
    return "You Lose!"
  }
};
console.log("Your choice was: " + userChoice);
console.log("The computer chose: " + computerChoice);
compare(userchoice, computerChoice);
```

This is the code I wrote. I haven't been able to troubleshoot it to see if it works, but I need a place to run it. Please help!!

Comment: You can't use `return` outside a function.

Comment: Googling ["js tester"](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+tester) comes up with a bunch of online options.

Comment: There are a number of online sites where you can test your code: jsfiddle.com, codepen.com

Comment: @Barmar You said that I can't use `return` outside a function. Can you tell me which line it is? I don't see how it is outside the function, but whenever I try running it, it says that there is an illegal return statement.

Comment: Most of the `if` statements are not in the `compare()` function.

Comment: You need to move all the `if` blocks that check for winning or losing into the `compare()` function. And they should be comparing `choice1` and `choice2`, not `userChoice` and `computerChoice`.

Comment: I tried moving everything into the compare function but it says unexpected end of input. What's the proper way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an html document then embed your javascript code into it.
Learn more here: [https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html#:~:text=To%20include%20our%20JavaScript%20file,file%20where%20it%20is%20stored](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-html#:%7E:text=To%20include%20our%20JavaScript%20file,file%20where%20it%20is%20stored).